# Interests on "caution deposit" for rental in Germany

Tags: germany, taxes, banking, international-law

Does the tenant of a flat have any rights on the interests matured on the "caution deposit" or do they belong to the landlord? If yes, according to what percentage should the interests be calculated?

Answer (score 2):

According to §551 BGB, the interests on the deposit belong to the tenant (except some cases, f.e. student dorms). Landlords have no rights on it (and they must save deposit separated from their own money)..

The percentage is just a usual bank percentage, so maybe 0.5% a year nowadays or even less.

Comment: Thank you. About the last remarks: doesn't every bank have a different interest rate (even though slighly so) depending on the type of account or on some promotions?

Comment: Yes, but rates are currently so low and tend to be inexistent so it doesn’t make any significant difference.

Comment: I know, but I wish to be very careful about these legal issues.